# MySQL - get information from table b using table a as where =

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code here, but it's not working I just get "No Process" on my display, I am trying to get the image URL from table B while using the title reference from table A. Any Help on what i am doing wrong?

```
<?php
$gettop="SELECT * FROM feeddb ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 3";
$gettop2=mysql_query($gettop) or die("Processing Error");
while($gettop3=mysql_fetch_array($gettop2))
{
echo "<div class='rt'></div>";
echo "<div class='right_articles'>";
$getimg="SELECT * FROM feedus where tit=".$gettop3['title'];
$getimg2=mysql_query($getimg) or die("No Process");
$getimg3=mysql_query_fetch_array($getimg2);
echo "<p><img src='$getimg3[img]' width='60' height='60' class='image' /><b>Feed: $gettop3[title]</b><br/>$gettop3[feedpost]<br><br><br><br></p>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If `$gettop3['title']` is a string, it will be **unquoted** in `$getimg` which makes it a erroneous query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be quoting `$gettop3['title']` like this

```
$getimg="SELECT * FROM feedus where tit='".$gettop3['title']."'";
```

Comment: I have changed it to: `$getimg="SELECT * FROM feedus where tit='".$gettop3['title']."' "; ` But now I don't get any error message. I tried it in the PHPMyAdmin but it returns the following: `Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0002 sec) ` with `SELECT * FROM feedus WHERE tit = 'test' LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: Can you `echo $getimg` and run the output in phpmyadmin? Maybe there is no matching data in `feedus`

Comment: It shows `Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0001 sec)` and shows the row in the listing underneath it. The hi, being the one im after. The echo outputs `SELECT * FROM feedus WHERE tit = 'hi' LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: The URL I am doing this on is: [link](http://feed.foa.me/Internet_Music) and it is meant to be appearing in the orange section on the right side.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($getimg3)`? When you do a view source of the page, what does the <img> tag look like?

Comment: Looking at the view source, it stops at `<div class='rt'></div><div class='right_articles'>` It's chops off everything after that... very strange.

Comment: FIXED IT! it's because I was doing mysql_query_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm curious why you didn't get an error for `mysql_query_fetch_array` because that is an invalid function.

Comment: I did, thats is how I found it, Silly me for not checking the error log in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo `mysql_error()` after the second query. And check `$getimg`.

EDIT:

I guess you should add quotes around `$gettop3['title']`, something like

```
$getimg = sprintf(
 "SELECT * FROM feedus where tit='%s'"
 , mysql_real_escape_string( $gettop3['title'] )
);
```

Comment: I got "Unknown column 'hi' in 'where clause'"